# where do I find Oracle Subtype in system Tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, subtype, plsql-package

I have created a package in oracle database with type and subtype. When I am trying to see the types and subtype in "ALL_TYPES" or "ALL_PLSQL_TYPES" i am able to see only type details but not subtype details. Where can i find subtype details in oracle system tables?

```
 Create or replace package TEST_PKG_NEW is
       subtype V_TYP is TEST01.st_spatial_references.sr_name%Type;
       type R_TYP is record(c1 pls_integer, c2 varchar2(100));
       procedure VARR_PROC(p1 in V_TYP, p2 OUT V_TYP);
       procedure REC_PROC(p1 in R_TYP, p2 OUT R_TYP);
    end TEST_PKG_NEW;
```

I have already created the "st_spatial_references" table with "sr_name" as column under "TEST01" user.

Comment: Which "details" are you looking for?  You can see its basics in DBA_IDENTIFIERS.  `select * from DBA_IDENTIFIERS where object_name = 'TEST_PKG_NEW' and name = 'V_TYP';`

Comment: I See  this table holding subtypes but  my package details are not available. The above query returning empty result set. All the subtypes in that table are system defined. I am not sure if its holding user defined subtypes.

Comment: You need to compile the package after enabling PLSQL identifiers.  I.e., `ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';`, then compile your package, then check `DBA_IDENTIFIERS`.  You still won't see the _structure_ of your subtype the way you can for the primary types.

Comment: Subtypes exist only within PL/SQL code, similar to variables. They are not exposed via the data dictionary like types.

Comment: Is there any other table or view which is equivalent to "SYS.ALL_TYPE_ATTRS" to get metadata of subtypes created specific to package ?

Comment: Hi @MatthewMcPeak I want to get subtype metadata like if a package is created with subtypes,which also contains a subtype "rowtype" then i need to get all list of  subtypes declared. If its a type i am able get them from ALL_TYPE_ATTRS but unable to do it for subtypes.

Comment: You can get a list of declared subtypes in a package using the method I gave you.  I.e., `alter session set plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';` then select from `DBA_IDENTIFIERS`.  What you will not be able to see is the structure of the subtype.